# puppet hash create file

Tags: puppet, resources

Sooo i have this hash in app1's puppet manifest

```
$applicaton = 'app1'

daemontools::build {
    $application:
        path     => "/opt/supervise/${application}"
        envvars  => {
            'ENVIRONMENT'              => $location,
            'SERVICE_USER'             => $application_user,
            'SERVICE_PORT'             => $gunicorn_port,
            'SERVICE_IP'               => $gunicorn_ip,
            'ADDITIONAL_PARAMS'        => "--workers $processorcount",
            'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'   => "${application}.settings",
        }
}
```

and this hash in my app2's puppet manifest

```
$applicaton = 'app2'

daemontools::build {
    $application:
        path     => "/opt/supervise/${application}"
        envvars  => {
            'ENVIRONMENT'              => $location,
            'SERVICE_USER'             => $application_user,
            'SERVICE_PORT'             => $gunicorn_port,
            'SERVICE_IP'               => $gunicorn_ip,
            'ADDITIONAL_PARAMS'        => "--workers $processorcount",
            'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'   => "${application}.settings",
        }
}
```

which are both passed to daemontools::build ( along with a path )

```
define daemontools::build (
$envvars = {},
$path
){
    $env_names = keys($envvars)
    daemontools::envfile { $env_names:
        path   => $path,
        value  => $envvars
    }
}
define daemontools::envfile($path, $value) {
    file { "/${path}/envdir/${name}" :
        mode    => 0644,
        content => "${value[$name]}";
    }
}
```

which results in

**Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Duplicate declaration: Daemontools::Envfile[SERVICE_IP] is already declared in file daemontools/manifests/build.pp:53; cannot redeclare at daemontools/manifests/build.pp:53**

How can i make it so that i wont get duplicate resource declarations?

Answer (score 3):

In the creation of your `daemontools::envfile` object, you should add a unique identifier to the `$name` of the object.

```
daemontools::envfile { $something_unique$env_names:
    path   => $path,
    value  => $envvars
}
```

By default, `$name` is each of your `$env_names`.  When you create the second object with the same set of keys, it causes many duplicates.  FQDN or something equally unique could be useful for lookup.

Answer (score 3):

Right, you're using `$env_names` (you may also want to look at consistent use of underscores there) as the `$name` for `daemontools::envfile` for semi-hacky iteration - I assume you don't want to use the `future` parser (quite reasonably). Note that also what you're trying to do with `value => $envvars` probably won't work either.

So, `prefix` from `puppetlabs/stdlib` is your friend for the duplicate issue, ensuring you get unique `$name`s by preconstructing the path:

```
define daemontools::build (
    $envvars = {},
    $path
) {
    $envnames = keys($envvars)
    $envfiles = prefix($envnames, "${path}/envdir/")
    daemontools::envfile {
        $envfiles:
            # Stuff
    }
}
```

However, this will probably just reveal that `value => $envvars` doesn't work, and seems to only lead to the conclusion that you *need* the `future` parser for now, and `each()`

Comment: definitely got me headed in the right direction. :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems this worked :) 
Although messy with that inline template...

```
    $env_names = keys($envvars)
    $prefixedenvnames = prefix($env_names, "${path}/envdir/")
    daemontools::envfile { $prefixedenvnames:
        value  => $envvars
    }
}

define daemontools::envfile($value) {
    $tmp = inline_template('<%= name.split("/").last %>')
    file { $name :
        mode    => 0644,
        content => "${value[$tmp]}";
    }
}
```